# PayPal discount can't make it work

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I'm trying to setup a discount for a the whole cart using PayPal + Codeigniter, I got this working withouth the discounts.

As far as I've read the only thing that I would need to do is set a hidden field *discount_amount_cart* as I saw [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload)

**Here is my form:**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypal_form">
     <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="biz_1271300483_biz@xxxx.xx" />
     <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://xxxxxx.com/website/pt/paypal/success/8/4c237a03897e0" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://xxxxxxx.com/website/pt/paypal/cancel/8/4c237a03897e0" />
     <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://xxxxxx.com/website/pt/paypal/ipn" />
     <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/images/logo.png" />
     <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/images/logo.png" />
     <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="4c237a03897e0" />
     <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_cart" value="10.00" />
     <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Foo Bar" />
     <input type="hidden" name="city" value="xxxx" />
     <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="xxxxxx" />
     <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="xxxxxx" />
     <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="pt" />
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="xxxxx@xxx.pt" />
     <input type="hidden" name="country" value="PT" />
     <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Cloud Hosting WIN Business 25GB" />
     <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="200.00000003" />
     <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="156" />
     <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate_1" value="20" />
     <p><input type="submit" name="pp_submit" value="Pagar" class="submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

But when I "post" the fields the discount line won't appear, do I need to activate something in the merchant account, am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it,

From the PayPal documentation:

> When you use consolidated discount amounts, you should specify a consolidated tax value in tax_cart. If you do not specify a tax value and your profile specifies a tax rate, your profile tax rate is applied after the consolidated discount value is applied.

So I need to define my "global" tax amount for the cart with *tax_cart*.

Comment: you also must delete all "tax_rate_X" and "tax_x" and give it the total order tax already calculated with "tax_rate"

Answer (score 2):

The name of your discount input appears to be wrong:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_rate_cart" value="10.00" />
```

should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="10" />
```

> Use discount_amount_cart to charge a
>   single discount amount for the entire
>   cart.
>
> Use discount_amount_x to set a
>   discount amount associated with item x
>
> Use discount_rate_cart to charge a
>   single discount percentage for the
>   entire cart.
>
> discount_rate_cart  -  Applies to
>   entire cart however, this variable
>   will only work with the "Upload"
>   Method.  Not the standard Add to Cart
>   variables.
>
> This variable will be ignored if you
>   are including any individual sales tax
>   amount or rate in your upload method
>   code.   This is because the sales tax
>   needs to be calculated after the
>   discount is applied to your items
>   therefore, the discount is applied to
>   the item Subtotal, not the Total.
>
> Note, If you just using the standard
>   Add to Cart buttons, there no Discount
>   variables for the entire cart.  as
>   they  "only" apply a Discount to an
>   individual item.

Comment: Hi stormdrain thanks for the anwser my problem was the tax_cart was not set, and appears that PayPal needs this to be set to apply the discount.