# Why is PayPal ignoring discount_amount_cart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I have been using PayPal Payments Standard. Everything has been working great. Now I want to add support for coupon discounts.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), the discount_amount_cart variable appears to be what I want:

> Single discount amount charged cart-wide. 
>   It must be less than the selling price of all items combined in the cart. This variable overrides any individual item discount_amount_x values, if present. 
>   Applies only to the Cart Upload command.

So, I add the variable to my form:

```
<form id="Paypal" name="Paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart">
    <input id="upload" name="upload" type="hidden" value="1">

    <input id="business" name="business" type="hidden" value="kelly@hopskipdesign.com">
    <input id="custom" name="custom" type="hidden" value="Client">
    <input id="discount_amount_cart" name="discount_amount_cart" 
        type="hidden" value="$4.00">
    <input id="tax_cart" name="tax_cart" type="hidden" value="$1.65">
    <input id="currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD">

    <input id="return" name="return" type="hidden" value="http://www.hopskipphotography.com/Order/Confirm/Client">
    <input id="cancel_return" name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://www.hopskipphotography.com/Order/Cart/Client">
    <input id="cbt" name="cbt" type="hidden" value="Place Order">

    <input id="item_name_1" name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="Photo #6">
    <input id="amount_1" name="amount_1" type="hidden" value="$20.00">
    <input id="item_number_1" name="item_number_1" type="hidden" value="B49A8382">
    <input id="quantity_1" name="quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1">

    <input id="item_name_2" name="item_name_2" type="hidden" value="Photo #10">
    <input id="amount_2" name="amount_2" type="hidden" value="$20.00">
    <input id="item_number_2" name="item_number_2" type="hidden" value="B49A8428">
    <input id="quantity_2" name="quantity_2" type="hidden" value="1">

    <div class="checkout-button">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" alt="Check out with PayPal">
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I click the button, everything appears *except* the discount:

[image: Your order summary - Total $41.65 USD]

I found a similar question where the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3112607/27482) was to use the tax_cart variable instead of tax_x. But I was already using tax_cart.

Any other ideas as to why discount_amount_cart is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike other amount variables, discount_amount_cart does not like dollar signs.

When I changed the field to:

```
<input id="discount_amount_cart" name="discount_amount_cart" 
    type="hidden" value="4.00">
```

PayPal displayed the discount:

[image: Your order summary - Discount -$4.00 - Total $37.65 USD]